# Where should I ask about computer science in veterinary sciences?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I'm interested in learning about what type of software do veterinarians use in their work. For example, I would like to ask something like "What specialistic software do veterinarian surgeons use, if any".

I believe this question falls into the "Medical Sciences" and "Bioinformatics" groups, but honestly not too sure and I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: I am not a member of either of those sites but I would have thought it is closer to medical science than bioinformatics. Your proposed question would be likely to be closed as opinion-based on sites where I do post but you may have other more specific ones in mind too.

Comment: I would reccomend posting something one each of the per-site metas asking wether it would be on topic there.